# What is the type of adjective that denotes capability?

Tags: english, adjectives

I have encountered a number of adjectives while programming that all have the same use case of describing capabilities of a noun. "Clonable", "serializable", "runnable", "hashable", "immutable", "iterable" are all examples of this and denote if an object has particular capability. Is there an adjective type that describes all of these -able adjectives?

Comment: "Adjectives with -_able_" is how I'd put it. With a footnote to the effect that it might well be spelled -_ible_. That's a modal suffix that can be attached to any active `Verb` to make an adjective that means 'able to `Verb`' or, in the case of patients rather than agents, 'able to be `Verb`-ed'. There's no special name for the class of words that have the suffix, any more than there is for the class of nouns that have the -_dom_ noun-forming suffix: _freedom, kingdom, martyrdom, princedom, dukedom, giggledom, boredom, whoredom,_ etc.

Comment: IIRC, Dwight Chapin wrote a dissertation, long ago, about the derivation of -able words from verbs.